# R - Dealing with multiple large arrays that can be individually stored/loaded

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I am dealing with a problem using `1000 x 1000 x 1000` arrays in `R`.  Each of these arrays takes up `7.6 Gb` when stored as standard array objects.  I want to be able to do a calculation involving two of these arrays to generate a much smaller object.

Using `64-bit R` my computer has enough memory to generate and save one array of this size at a time, so I have succeeded at saving both arrays as `rmd` files on my hard drive.  However, when I try to load both of these arrays in the same session, in order to do a calculation that uses both of them, the second load leads to memory problems (i.e., `Error: Cannot allocate vector of size...`).

**Question:** What is the simplest/best way to deal with memory problems that arise when you want to use two objects of this kind, that are sufficiently small to be loaded individually, but too large to be loaded together?

Comment: Have a look to`bigmemory` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf. Also maybe your computation can be optimized, Are you sure you need to load everything at once?

Comment: @JRR: Can that package handle three-dimensional arrays?  Because the language of the package seems to indicate that it only deals with matrices (i.e., two-dimensional arrays).

Comment: I don't know. Seems you'r right. What about `ff` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html